# How should I use the word "kludge"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I was looking for a word that means “do some work quickly and improvised”, and found *kludge*. Is this the right word?

And, if it is okay, what is the correct usage? Can I use the word in a formal or informal conversation (or written)?

Comment: Growing up in Glasgow in the 1960s, I was familiar with this word. It was slang for a toilet.

Comment: @NigelJ Yes, but that is apparently an unrelated word. All attempts to connect the two have failed. See [WorldWideWords](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-klu1.htm)

Comment: @PhilSweet Thank you. It is the first time in my life I have ever seen the word written down. I have only ever known it phonetically, hence the mistake.

Comment: Note that there is disagreement (in the nerd community) as to whether it's "kludge" or "kluge".  And, yes, it's definitely informal (though in a sense that is far removed from "street talk").  Best definition I've ever heard of it is "deviously clever".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After rattling around in the language for more than a half century, ***Kludge*** has been around long enough to have crawled up from the slime of geek-speak and begun the evolutionary journey toward common speech.  It refers to any sloppy but expedient solution to an exigent problem, with a special denotation in electronic and engineering contexts of

> *a strange assortment of ill-matched parts combining to form a distressing whole.*

While non-engineers may use it with growing impunity, the word remains rooted in technology.  The etymology noted in the Wiktionary article on the word is perhaps indicative:

> Perhaps from British military slang, possibly based on a Scots word kludge or kludgie (“common toilet”), or perhaps from German klug (“clever”). Alternatively, possibly related to Polish klucz (“a key, a hint, a main point”) and Russian ключ (ključ, “key, clue”).
>
> Alternatively, perhaps from to Dutch Low Saxon klütje (“(little) dumpling, clod”), Jutland Danish klyt (“piece of bad workmanship, klud(g)e”); compare and standard Danish kludder (“mess, disorder”). (Compare klutz.)
>
> There is evidence that kluge (which see) was once a separate word with similar meaning but separate derivation, but the spelling kludge was widely popularized in the US by a 1962 Datamation article on “How to Design a Kludge”, and since then the two words have often been used as alternative spellings of each other.

It would be difficult to draw a line between the formality and informality of ***Kludge***, since it appears to have gained a good deal of currency: See this [Google N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kludge&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckludge%3B%2Cc0) indicating increasing popularity since the 1960's.  The word does have a distinctly humorous connnotation, however.  Witness this brief excerpt from the 1962 *Datamation* article "How to Maintain a Kludge " (referenced above):

```
Don't put all the fuses and circuit breakers in one 
place. Hide a few in obscure spots. Include some that give 
no visible indication when tripped; these are best placed 
behind something. It's an easy rule: the less chance there 
is for a fuse to trip, the more you hide it.
```

Comment: kludge
a fanciful, humorous coinage by U.S. author Jackson W. Granholm (1921-2007), "ill-assorted collection of poorly-matching parts, forming a distressing whole" (Granholm's definition), 1962, also as a verb. It persisted in the jargon of computer programmers for quick-and-dirty fixes in code. Related: Kludged; kludgy. https://www.etymonline.com/word/kludge

Comment: @KarlG - Thanks, and +1 for running Granholm to ground!

Comment: Infinitely more likely than some computer guy grabbing a word from Low German or Danish.

Comment: @KarlG - This is essentially the etymology I heard -- from a Dutchman.

Comment: `Step 1:` be a programmer.

`Step 2:` use the word 'kludge' lots.

`Step 3:` profit.

Answer (score 0):

“Kludge” is very definitely a ***strongly*** colloquial usage; more, I don’t think I’ve ever heard it used outside the IT industry. I do hear it used as both a noun and a verb: “I think I can *kludge* something together to do that” (verb), or “that’s an awful *kludge*; make sure you clean it up before we go live” (noun).

Comment: I agree that it's informal; I wouldn't say that it's specific to IT, though.

Comment: @TRiG - Nor do I say that it is; only that I haven't heard it used outside IT.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a word that means:

> “do some work quickly and improvised”

A kludge for using `kludge` could be using the adjective [`provisional`](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/provisional):

> for the present time but likely to change

You could say:

> "This is not the final version, it's just a provisional attempt."

---

I think `kludge` is fine as a noun or a verb. Some definitions:

- [unsophisticated but fairly effective solution to a problem](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kludge)
- [quick, messy but functional fix or workaround to a problem](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kludge)
- [haphazard or makeshift solution to a problem and especially to a computer or programming problem](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kludge)
- [marginal adaptation that compensates for, but does not eliminate fundamental design inefficiencies](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.433.5883&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Example sentences:

> - [The server chassis was snapped in two, but I've kludged it together with electrical tape.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kludge)
> - [And as for the kludge, he's target-practice.](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=andromeda&episode=s02e07)
> - [Hugh had to kludge something together.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kludge)
> - [People outside of AI sometimes detect a programming kludge.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/kludge)

It can be used both formally and informally.